# How to construct a Uri whose baseaddress is the current domain it is deployed in?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api

I have a asp.net mvc application with webapi as well. While my MVC controllers get the user requests, they call the webapi layer to get the actual data from the database.

Since I may move the WebAPI to a separate project later, I am calling the webapi by creating a HttpClient in my controller code.

The code below works well when deployed locally, but when I deploy it in Azure Website, it fails because of the baseaddress being localhost.

```
var baseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost");
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { UseCookies = false })
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
{
    var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
    var result = await client.SendAsync(message);
    ...
}
```

QUESTION: Assuming the webapi and webserver will run in the same domain, how can I create the Uri where the baseaddress is the domain where the code is deployed instead of being hardcoded ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a simple single C# line

```
Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)
```

This will get you the left part of the current url it is being called on. However this won't work if you are using it in a WorkerRole, it must be part of a web request. (i.e. the HttpContext must be valid and not null)